# printing the date using string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

def date(month, day,    year):

o Restriction:  you must    use string  formatting  %

examples:

date(2,29,2016) → "02/29/2016"

date(11,8,2008) → "11/08/2008"

date(1,3,1) → "01/03/000

so this is my task, and so far I have this
def date(month,day,year):

```
print("%2d" % month, "%2d" %day, "%4d" %year")
```

I am just learning how to use this % function so I am a bit lost on why my code isnt working. My logic is that I want 2 integers for the month and day and 4 for the year. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You've got an extra quote after `year`. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
print ("%02d/%02d/%04d" % ( month, day, year ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

strftime() method, available on any date/datetime/time variable, will work, although I'm not 100% sure from your description it's legal for you:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

```
d = date(2, 29, 2016)
print(d.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferred syntax for formatting strings in Python is now [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

> This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the `%` formatting described in [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) in new code.
>   
> - [Python 2.7 docs on str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Here's how you would write the `date_string` function using `str.format`:

```
def date_string(month, day, year):
    return "{:02d}/{:02d}/{:04d}".format(month, day, year)
```

And, as you can see, it works for all of your examples:

```
In [1]: def date_string(month, day, year):
   ...:     return "{:02d}/{:02d}/{:04d}".format(month, day, year)
   ...: 

In [2]: date_string(2,29,2016)
Out[2]: '02/29/2016' 

In [3]: date_string(11,8,2008)
Out[3]: '11/08/2008'

In [4]: date_string(1,3,1)
Out[4]: '01/03/0001'
```